# How to deploy NebulaGraph Database on Windows 10？

Tags: database, graph, nebula-graph

The basic information is as below:

NebulaGraph Database version is 2.5.0
Deployment way is stand-alone on Windows 10

I want to deploy Exchange on Windows 10 based on NebulaGraph Database v2.5.0.
Not sure which basic components are required and the version, like the version of scala, java, spark. And there are not any basic configuration on the machine. Does anyone have operation guide?

Comment: Guide recommendation questions are off-topic for reasons explained in #3 of [/help/on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). The exception is that you are allowed to ask for links to official documentaiton/guides ("official" meaning that the resource is written by the people/organization who maintains the software the guide is for). Are you asking for an official guide? If so, please [edit] to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by myself after a lot of attempts. If you have the same situation, try the following statement:

```
CREATE tag p2( fatherModelCode string DEFAULT '609946853282156544_1',MD5 string,  );
```